# Bash script to run command and show console output until some phrase appears or timeout

Tags: linux, bash, .net-core, pipe

I am trying to build a bash script to run a web server. I need the script to show output of web server in console until specific word appears on the console indicating either the server initialization completed successfully or some error occurs.

I was able to show the console output until timeout occurs:

```
#!/bin/bash
(exec /opt/aspnetcore-runtime-3.0.0-linux-x64/dotnet /opt/app/Launcher.dll &) | (timeout --foreground 6 cat; cat > /dev/null &)
```

If an error happens earlier than 6 seconds, then the web server stopped and the control goes back to the terminal, which is the desired behavior.

However, if the web server initialization was successfully completed in 2 seconds, the user must wait for another 4 seconds until the script finishes. I want to return the control back to terminal once some phrase (e.g. `SUCCESS INIT!`) appear on the console.

Comment: What is the success message ? Does it go to stderr or stdout ?

Comment: @dash-o something like `SUCCESS INIT!` on stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On surface, replacing the current wait ('cat') with a custom loop that will exit when 'SUCCESS INIT!' is found will address the problem

Such a loop can be implemented with

```
while read x && echo "$x" && [ "$x" != "SUCCESS INIT!" ] ; do : ; done
```

And the combined command

```
(Launch-command &) | (timeout --foreground 6 sh -c 'while read x && echo "$x" && [ "$x" != "SUCCESS INIT!" ] ; do : ; done' ; cat > /dev/null &)
```

Not very elegant. If you can, put the 'timeout ... while ...' in a separate script. I did not test, but it should work:

```
#! /bin/bash
# wait-line.sh
timeout --foreground "$1" sh -c "while read x && echo "$x" && [ "$x" != "$2" ] ; do : done "
cat > /dev/null
```

And then the original command line will look like

```
( Launch-command ... & ) | ( wait-line.sh 6 "SUCCESS INIT!" &)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.